# List (and then delete) all folders with no files

Tags: cmd, directory, subdirectory

I'd like to find all the folders under a specific path (C:\main_folder) that have no files in it.

I've found a way with cmd for doing it:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "folder=C:\main_folder"
for /r "%folder%" /d %%F in (.) do dir /b "%%F" | findstr "^" >nul || (echo %%~fF) > "C:\empty_folders_list.txt"
```

but if I have
`C:\main_folder\folder_1` containing `folder_2` and no files and
`C:\main_folder\folder_1\folder_2` with no files, that code gives only
`C:\main_folder\folder_1\folder_2`, while I'd like to have also 
`C:\main_folder\folder_1` in it.

It shouldn't look only to the folders that have no files, cause I can have
`C:\main_folder\folder_3` containing `folder_4` and no files but if
`C:\main_folder\folder_3\folder_4` contains file, `folder_3` and `folder_4` shouldn't be listed.

And after having the list I want to delete them (the list is only for checking/saving them).

How do I write it?
Thanks!

Comment: You should try `dir /b /s /a-d "%%F"` and see how that goes.

Comment: Thanks.
Tried this

    @echo off
    setlocal
    set "folder=C:\main_folder"
    for /r "%folder%" /d %%F in (.) do dir /b /s /a-d "%%F" | findstr "^" >nul || (echo %%~fF) > "C:\empty_folders_list.txt" 

but it's writing only
C:\main_folder\folder_1\folder_2...

Answer (score 0):

If you are a supported Windows system, it will have PowerShell. This requires PowerShell 3.0+, but can be done with 2.0 with some modifications.

This gathers the list of subdirectories and sorts the names descending. This is so that an empty directory that had empty subdirectories will be removed.

When you are satisfied that the correct directories will be removed, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Remove-Item` command.

=== Remove-Empties.ps1

```
$baseDir = 'C:\main_folder'
$dirs = (Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse -Path $baseDir).FullName | Sort-Object -Descending
foreach ($dir in $dirs) {
    if (((Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path $dir).Length -eq 0) -and
        ((Get-ChildItem -File -Path $dir | Measure-Object).Count -eq 0)) {
        "Removing directory $($dir)"
        Remove-Item -Path $dir -WhatIf
    }
}
```

=== Invoke from cmd.exe command line or .bat file script

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File ".\Remove-Empties.ps1" >"C:\empty_folders_list.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks. With that I got

"Removing directory C:\main_folder\folder_1\folder_2
What if: Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target "C:\main_folder\folder_1\folder_2"."

but it's not saying that also C:\main_folder\folder_1 is empty...

In $baseDir I have to write my main path? Or should I add '/src/t' to it?

Comment: I assume you changed the first line to `$baseDir = 'C:\main_folder'`. The reason it is not removing `folder1` is because `folder2` was not actually deleted because of the `-WhatIf`. `folder` still contains `folder2`, so it is not to be removed.

Comment: When you remove `-WhatIf`, I expect it will show `folder1` being removed.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "folder=C:\temp\bob"
for /r "%folder%" /d %%F in (.) do dir /b /s /a-d "%%F" 2>nul | findstr "^" >nul || echo %%~fF
```

output:

```
C:\temp>test
C:\temp\bob\empty parent
C:\temp\bob\empty parent\empty subfolder
C:\temp\bob\not empty parent\empty subfolder
```

Comment: True, it's working perfectly.

My problem was
    (echo %%~fF) > "C:\empty_folders_list.txt"

for writing the file, cause inside that there's only the last folder...
How do I get them all in that file?

And how to delete them then?
Thanks!

Comment: use `>>` instead of `>`.  Append instead of overwrite.